# Set width to fill_parent to Linearlayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am using slider panel in my application.

Now, my problem is that when I rotate device screen to portrait, Its width does not change. I tried changing some code and Its width was being perfect but was also getting error. so please check this.

My code is as follow. slidingPanel is LinearLayout so need to set width to it.

**Code:**

```
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
panelWidth = (int) ((metrics.widthPixels) * 0.70);

headerPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
headerPanelParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) headerPanel
            .getLayoutParams();
headerPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
headerPanel.setLayoutParams(headerPanelParameters);

menuPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
menuPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) menuPanel
            .getLayoutParams();
menuPanelParameters.width = panelWidth;
menuPanel.setLayoutParams(menuPanelParameters);

slidingPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);
slidingPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slidingPanel
            .getLayoutParams();
slidingPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
slidingPanel.setLayoutParams(slidingPanelParameters);
```

Comment: where is your FrameLayout?

Comment: sorry, its linearlayout. slidingPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);

Comment: I need to set width to slidingPanelParameters.

Comment: have you the orientation flag inside your Manifest?

Comment: yes. I have flag it. how to set fill_parent width to slidingPanelParameters ? cz it is affecting everything.

Comment: I will remove it (the orientation flag) and provide a different Layout inside the layout-land folder. In this way when your activity restarts you have the appropriate layout in landscape

Comment: bt that time, activity starts again thats d problem.

Comment: why is a problem. When your activity restarts the correct layout will be choose

Answer (score 0):

FILL_PARENT is represented by the static final int [ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT).  But note that since API version 8, FILL_PARENT has been and replaced by MATCH_PARENT.  So use that in your LinearLayout.LayoutParams objects to set FILL_PARENT programatically.

Comment: ohk, then how to assign that width to slidingPanelParameters ?

Comment: Doesn't `slidingPanelParameters.width = ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT;` work?

Comment: then it is compressing that part means in remaining width, it shows activity when anyone click on button for slider menu.

Comment: please reply sir. what to set there ?

Comment: You've programmed menuPanel to take 70% of the width, so there's only 30% left for sliding panel.  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: i just dnt want to compress that part when anyone opens sliders. cz it does not look good.

Comment: In that case I think your problem won't be solved by a setting of LinearLayout.LayoutParams.width.  If you want your sliding panel to be on top, then I think that needs to be programmed in a different way.